# SQLite: Add columns on the fly if they don't exist

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi

```
sub insert {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $data = $self->{data};
    my $keys = join( ', ', keys $data);
    my $values = join( ', ', map qq('$_'),  values $data);
    my $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl ($keys) VALUES ($values);";
    my $sth = $self->{dbh}->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
}
```

I have a method that inserts the contents of a hash ref into a one table sqlite database. I was wondering if there was a simple way to add a column to the table if the hash key is not already a column. Obviously if one of the keys is not a column name, the insert will fail. Can I capitalize on that failure, add the missing columns, and redo the insert. Or would I have to check all columns against all the keys each time I want to insert into the database? (All keys have TEXT values)

Comment: Issue an ALTER statement for each key. It'll fail if the column already exists, or it'll create the column if it doesn't.

Comment: Catching the failure (with `eval` or something like Try::Tiny) and inserting the column will work as well.

Comment: @ikegami - Executing an Alter for every single column, every single time I want to insert would be pretty costly

Comment: So keep track which one's you've already attempted.

Answer (score 2):

Alter your table based on the info you get using `PRAGMA`

```
my $inf_query = $db->prepare("PRAGMA table_info('tbl')");
$inf_query->execute();
my @inf = map { $_->[1] } @{$inf_query->fetchall_arrayref()};
```

`@inf` will be an array containing the columns present in the table, and you can use that info to construct your `ALTER` query.

**Edited to return an array you can use to grep ;)**

Comment: Is $inf an array ref of arrays? Do I have to do a nested foreach loop to compare the column names? I would love to just grep(/column_name/, @list_of_columns)

Comment: @Takkun Very well, I edited it and now it returns an array you can use to grep ;)